# dataTable and managedBean

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsf

I´m new in JSF. I´m doing a basic Edit/delete dataTable with the option of setting the atribute "active" (ativo) of a user to true/false. My whole datatable works just fine, show the user data and I can edit/remove users, but the "setActive" just doesn´t work as intended. The code is based on a book I´m reading, I read alot of times the code again, tried to debug, made some "println" to debug var stats but nothing seem to work.
If i try to "edit" the "active" state in another form, it saves properly on mysql.I hope i can get some help on that.

There´s the problem with a screenshot and code, any help will be apreciated.

Screen:

[image: Screen]

In the screen. The smile link represents user active/inactive, When i click the "smile" link, its suposed to reverse the state, active become inactive and so on.
but it just dosen't work. All the smiles are always the same, even if in the database the values are not equals. When I click the first time. it looks like nothing happens.But it calls the "ativar" in the managedBean and change the "usuario.ativo" state. but dosen´t change anything on screen or save in database.

When i click like 2 or 3 times. the smiles (and true/false text, used for debug) changes, but it changes for every record. And still dosen´t save.

So, the button/smile link does not work and it also does not show in the browser the real state of the property in the database.

I use SQL5 and hibernate. Ill post the code now.

Usuario.java - Entity class

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7573666040150534335L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer codigo;
    private String nome;
    @org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId //define uma chave natural.Que nao eh primary key
    private String email;
    @org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId //define uma chave natural.Que nao eh primary key
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private Date nascimento;
    private String celular;
    private String idioma;
    @Column
    private boolean ativo;

    public Usuario() {
        super();
    }
    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    public Date getNascimento() {
        return nascimento;
    }
    public void setNascimento(Date nascimento) {
        this.nascimento = nascimento;
    }
    public String getCelular() {
        return celular;
    }
    public void setCelular(String celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }
    public String getIdioma() {
        return idioma;
    }
    public void setIdioma(String idioma) {
        this.idioma = idioma;
    }
    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return ativo;
    }
    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (ativo ? 1231 : 1237);
        result = prime * result + ((celular == null) ? 0 : celular.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((idioma == null) ? 0 : idioma.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((login == null) ? 0 : login.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nascimento == null) ? 0 : nascimento.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((senha == null) ? 0 : senha.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
        if (ativo != other.ativo)
            return false;
        if (celular == null) {
            if (other.celular != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!celular.equals(other.celular))
            return false;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (idioma == null) {
            if (other.idioma != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!idioma.equals(other.idioma))
            return false;
        if (login == null) {
            if (other.login != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!login.equals(other.login))
            return false;
        if (nascimento == null) {
            if (other.nascimento != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nascimento.equals(other.nascimento))
            return false;
        if (nome == null) {
            if (other.nome != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
            return false;
        if (senha == null) {
            if (other.senha != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!senha.equals(other.senha))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuario [codigo=" + codigo + ", nome=" + nome + ", email=" + email + ", login=" + login + ", senha="
                + senha + ", nascimento=" + nascimento + ", celular=" + celular + ", idioma=" + idioma + ", ativo="
                + ativo + "]";
    }

}
```

XHTML that renders the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Administração de usuarios</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

<h1>Cadastro de usuarios</h1>
<br/>
<h:form>

    <h:messages/>
    <!-- usurio eh variavel/propriedae com dados da linha (usuario) -->
    <h:dataTable value="#{usuarioBean.lista}" var="usuario" rules="rows" cellpadding="5">

        <f:facet name="caption">
            A listagem a seguir exibe relacao de todos os usuarios do sistema. É possivel ativar/desativar, excluir e editar os mesmos.
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="header">Listagem de usuarios</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="footer">Fim da listagem</f:facet>

        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.ativo}  "/>
            <h:commandLink action="#{usuarioBean.ativar}">
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="usuario_ativo_#{usuarioBean.usuario.ativo}.png" style="border:0"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{usuario}" target="#{usuarioBean.usuario}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column> 

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Codigo</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.codigo}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="bandeira_#{usuario.idioma}.png"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
            #{usuario.nome}
        </h:column>


        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">e-Mail</f:facet>
            <a href="mailto:#{usuario.email}">#{usuario.email}</a>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:commandLink action="#{usuarioBean.editar}" >
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="editar16.png" style="border:0"/>
                <!-- Passa valor da linha para o bean, setando propriedade usuario  -->
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{usuario}" target="#{usuarioBean.usuario}"/>
                <!-- Passa um valor fixo de navegacao para usuarioBean.destinoSalvar a fim de  ser a saida de editar -->
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="/admin/principal" target="#{usuarioBean.destinoSalvar}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:commandLink action="#{usuarioBean.excluir}" 
                onclick="if (!confirm('Deseja excluir #{usuario.nome}?' )) return false;">
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="excluir16.png" style="border:0"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{usuario}" target="#{usuarioBean.usuario}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <h:commandLink action="#{usuarioBean.mostrar}">
                Show
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{usuario}" target="#{usuarioBean.usuario}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>


    </h:dataTable>

</h:form>
<br/>
<a href="../index.jsf">Inicio</a>

</h:body>

</html>
```

managedBean

```
package control;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import business.UsuarioRN;
import entity.Usuario;

@ManagedBean(name="usuarioBean") //nome padrao 
@RequestScoped
public class UsuarioBean {
    private Usuario usuario;
    private String confirmarSenha;

    private List<Usuario> lista;
    private String destinoSalvar;


    public UsuarioBean() {
        super();
        this.usuario=new Usuario();
    }

    /**
     * retorna o usuario
     * @return
     */
    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    /**
     * define usuario
     * @param usuario
     */
    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    /**
     * retorna confirma senha
     * @return
     */
    public String getConfirmarSenha() {
        return confirmarSenha;
    }

    /**
     * seta confirmarsenha
     * @param confirmarSenha
     */
    public void setConfirmarSenha(String confirmarSenha) {


        this.confirmarSenha = confirmarSenha;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getDestinoSalvar() {
        return destinoSalvar;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param destinoSalvar
     */
    public void setDestinoSalvar(String destinoSalvar) {

        this.destinoSalvar = destinoSalvar;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna lista de usuarios cadastrados
     * @return
     */
    public List<Usuario> getLista() {
        //Se a lista for null. Usado como flag e para verificar alteracoes.
        if (this.lista==null){
            //carrega nova lista do BD
            this.lista=new UsuarioRN().listar(); 
        }
        return this.lista;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo desnecessario
     * Retorna lista de usuarios
     * @param lista
     */
    public void setLista(List<Usuario> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }


    /**
     * Define novo usuario com "ativo" true e pagina de sucesso ao fim do cadastro de novo.
     * @return
     */
    public String novo(){
        //Define pagina a ser carregada apos execucao. Se for novo user, ir para usuariosucesso
        this.destinoSalvar="usuariosucesso";
        this.usuario=new Usuario();
        this.usuario.setAtivo(true);
        return "/publico/usuario"; //.jsf?      
    }
    /**
     * Salva dados do formulario. Seja novo usuario ou edição. A diferenca eh dada pela chamada do metodo "novo"
     * em caso de novos usuarios
     * @return
     */
    public String salvar(){
        //Context da mensagem
        FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        //pega a senha
        String senha=this.usuario.getSenha();
        //compara senha e confirmacao
        if (!senha.equals(this.confirmarSenha)){
            //Erro caso senha seja confirmada incorretamente
            FacesMessage message=new FacesMessage("A senha não foi confirmada corretamente.");
            context.addMessage(null, message);
            return null; //mantem na mesma pagina

        }
        //Caso nao tenha havido erros, grava o usuario e direciona para destinosalvar, que pode ser lista ou pagina de sucesso.
        new UsuarioRN().salvar(this.usuario);
        //carrega pagina de acordo com resultado.
        return this.destinoSalvar;
    }

    /**
     * Edita dados do usuario.
     * @return
     */
    public String editar(){
        //Apenas pega a senha e copia em confirmar senha e carrega pagina de inclusao/edicao.
        this.confirmarSenha=this.usuario.getSenha();
        return "/publico/usuario";
    }

    /**
     * Exclui usuario cadastrado
     * @return
     */
    public String excluir(){
        //Exclui usuario
        new UsuarioRN().excluir(usuario);;
        //Ao definir a lista como null. Forca o "getLista()" a recarregar os dados do BD.
        this.lista=null;
        return null;

    }

    /**
     * Ativa usuario
     * @return
     */
    public String ativar(){

        //inverte estado de ativo
        System.out.println(lista);
        if (this.usuario.isAtivo())
            this.usuario.setAtivo(false);
        else
            this.usuario.setAtivo(true); 

        //Salva os dados
        new UsuarioRN().salvar(this.usuario);
        System.out.println(lista);
        return null;
    }

    public String mostrar(){
        System.out.println("**********************************************************");
        System.out.println(usuario);
        System.out.println(lista);
        return null;
    }


}
```

Business class that save, delete, edit, get a list of records..

```
package business;

import java.util.List;

import entity.Usuario;
import persistense.UsuarioDaoHibernate;
import util.DaoFactory;

/**
 * Classe de regra de negocios para Usuario
 * @author X8
 *
 */
public class UsuarioRN {

    private UsuarioDaoHibernate usuarioDao;

    /** http://i.imgur.com/gVqtsR8.png
     * Cria UsuarioDaoHibernate no construtor
     */
    public UsuarioRN() {
        super();
        //Retorna UsuarioDao. Cast para UsuarioDaoHibernate.
        this.usuarioDao=(UsuarioDaoHibernate) DaoFactory.criarUsuarioDao();

    }

    /**
     * Retorna um unico usuario pelo seu codigo unico.
     * @param codigo
     * @return
     */
    public Usuario carregar(Integer codigo){
        return this.usuarioDao.carregar(codigo);
    }

    /**
     * Retorna um unico usuario atravez de seu login unico.
     * @param login
     * @return
     */
    public Usuario buscaPorLogin(String login){
        return this.usuarioDao.buscarPorLogin(login);
    }


    /**
     * Salva dados de usuario novo ou ja existente.
     * @param usuario
     */
    public void salvar(Usuario usuario){
        Integer codigo=usuario.getCodigo();
        //codigo nulo ou zero, usuario nunca foi salvo. Eh novo
        if (codigo==null || codigo==0){
            this.usuarioDao.salvar(usuario);
        } else {
            this.usuarioDao.atualizar(usuario); 
        }

    }

    /**
     * Exclui usuario cadastrado.
     * @param usuario
     */
    public void excluir(Usuario usuario){
        this.usuarioDao.excluir(usuario);
    }

    /**
     * Lista todos os usuarios cadastrados
     * @return
     */
    public List<Usuario> listar(){
        return this.usuarioDao.listar();
    }
}
```

Filter that starts/ends/commit the Hibernate connection/transaction:

```
package filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;


import util.HibernateUtil;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"*.jsf"})
public class ConexaoHibernateFilter implements Filter{

    private SessionFactory sf;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        //Criar sessao do Hibernate
        this.sf=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Pegar sessao corrente
        Session currentSession=this.sf.getCurrentSession();

        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {
          transaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
          //passa processamento do aplicativo para ser realisado (save(),delete(), etc)
          chain.doFilter(request,response);
          //Processamento foi concluido, entao salva com commit
          transaction.commit();

          if (currentSession.isOpen()) {
            currentSession.close();
          }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
          try {
              //Substitui transaction.isActive();
              //if (transaction.getStatus()!= TransactionStatus.ACTIVE) {
              if (!transaction.isActive()) {
                  transaction.rollback();
            }
          } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
          }
          throw new ServletException(ex);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}

Dao Class:

package persistense;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import entity.Usuario;

public class UsuarioDaoHibernate implements UsuarioDao {

    private Session session; 

    public UsuarioDaoHibernate() {

    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void salvar(Usuario usuario) {
        this.session.save(usuario);

    }

    @Override
    public void atualizar(Usuario usuario) {
        this.session.update(usuario);

    }

    @Override
    public void excluir(Usuario usuario) {
        this.session.delete(usuario);

    }

    @Override
    public Usuario carregar(Integer codigo) {
        Usuario u=(Usuario) this.session.get(Usuario.class, codigo);
        return u;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Usuario> listar() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Usuario> usuarios=this.session.createCriteria(Usuario.class).list();
        return usuarios;
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario buscarPorLogin(String login) {
        /*Criteria criteria=this.session.createCriteria(Usuario.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("login", login));
        //considerando login unico.
        return (Usuario)criteria.uniqueResult();*/

        //Fazendo com HQL       
        String hql="select u from Usuario u where u.login = :login";
        Query consulta=this.session.createQuery(hql);
        consulta.setString("login",login);
        return (Usuario) consulta.uniqueResult();

    }

}
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nacionalsal</groupId>
    <artifactId>Financeirolivro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Projeto Financeiro</name>
    <description>Projeto Financeiro</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jvnet-nexus-releases</id>
            <name>jvnet-nexus-releases</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>  


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>




        <!--  Verificar em caso de erro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate core 
        http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Hibernate Util:

```
package util;

import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory  = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registradorServico = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

            registradorServico.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());

            StandardServiceRegistry servico = registradorServico.build();

            return cfg.buildSessionFactory(servico); 


    } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Criação inicial do objeto SessionFactory falhou. Erro: " + e);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Hibernate CFG

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Configuração da conexão com o banco MySQL e dialeto -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/financeiro1</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">lalalala</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> 

        <!-- Configurações de debug -->

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

        <!-- Mapeando classes --> 

        <mapping class="entity.Usuario"/>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: You're referencing `#{usuarioBean.usuario.ativo}` instead of `#{usuario.ativo}`.

Comment: Thank you for see what i didn´t.

Comment: In a future question, we would appreciate if you post a [mcve] instead of an unfiltered code dump of which more than 90% is irrelevant to the problem.